# How to add text to a circle object in fabricJS?

Tags: jquery, canvas, frontend, fabricjs, web-frontend

I search here  [fabricJS-circle](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Circle.html) , and not found there is a way to add text like number 1 or 2 or 3... Inside a circle on canvas?

This is my circle object on canvas:

```
function makeStaion(left, top, stationID) {
    var c = new fabric.Circle({
        left: left,
        top: top,
        radius: 2,
        fill: '#5afffa',
        stroke: '#666',
        selectable: true,
        centeredScaling:true,
        padding:2,
        hasRotatingPoint: false,
        borderColor: 'black',
        cornerColor: 'black'

    });
    c.hasControls = true;
    c.station = true;

    c.stationID = stationID;
    c.stationName = stations[stationID].name;
    c.description = stations[stationID].desc;
    c.image = stations[stationID].image;

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Miss.Moran you need to update the Code you tried for getting some help(answers). Refer:- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask there are more chances not to close your query as off topic ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a fabric group.

Tutorial here: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#groups

Docs here: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html

try something like this:

```
var c = new fabric.Circle({
        left: left,
        top: top,
        radius: 2,
        fill: '#5afffa',
        stroke: '#666',
        selectable: true,
        centeredScaling:true,
        padding:2,
        hasRotatingPoint: false,
        borderColor: 'black',
        cornerColor: 'black'
    });

var t = new fabric.Text(stationID, {
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        fontSize: 1.2,
        textAlign: 'center',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        left: LayoutCoordX(STA),
        top: LayoutCoordY(BL-BLOffset)-radius-.4
    });

var g = new fabric.Group([c, t],{
        // any group attributes here
    });


    g.hasControls = true;
    g.station = true;

    g.stationID = stationID;
    g.stationName = stations[stationID].name;
    g.description = stations[stationID].desc;
    g.image = stations[stationID].image;

    return g;
```

Comment: Thanks!! I add the Text object and add to canvas the group - pair of Circle and Text object and it work great!!  :)

Comment: you know how I can change the border-radius of the circle? I want to change it when the circle scales parameters > 1.

Comment: You're looking for the strokeWidth attribute, I suspect. `var c = new fabric.Circle({ ... strokeWidth: 2.5 ... })`